# Mount NFS error on Centos8

Tags: linux, centos, synology

Mount shared folder via NFS into Synology but showing error. What did i missing here?

`[root@localhost ~]# mount -t nfs 192.168.1.20:/volume1/NetBackup`

`mount: 192.168.1.20:/volume1/NetBackup: can't find in /etc/fstab.`

As per their site said https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

[Preview of synology manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zXgb.gif)

Answer (score 4):

Where do you want to mount it? You forgot to specify the mount point.

If you do that, then `mount` looks in `/etc/fstab` to see if you put the mount point there. You did not, so `mount` must fail.

Comment: I did mentioned above that i want to mount into Synology . Client is Centos8 and to mount into Synology via NFS

Comment: @Daniel Yes, but **where** in the client's filesystem? Again, you forgot to specify this.